# MvvmCross binding in a view hierarchy

Tags: ios, xamarin, binding, mvvmcross

I've problem with creating binding to a custom view (hierarchy of views) in Xamarin.iOS with MvvmCross.

My custom control shows some text and has few buttons.

In code it looks something like this (simplyfied version, my last attempt)

```
// Custom control
public class CustomView : MvxView
{
    // Views
    private TextFieldWithImageButton TextField;
    // ...

    // Properties
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return TextField.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            TextField.Text = value;
        }
    }
    // ...
}

// ViewModel for Controller
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private string _text = "";
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; }
    }
    // ...
}

// ViewController
public class MainViewController : MvxViewController
{
    // Views
    private CustomView CustomView;

    // ViewModel
    public MainViewModel ViewModel;

    // ... intialization and other stuff

    // Binding ... called from ViewDidLoad method
    private void CreateBinding()
    {
        var set = CustomView.CreateBindingSet<CustomView, MainViewModel>();
        set.Bind(CustomView.Text).To(ViewModel.Text);
        set.Apply();
    }
}
```

But I always get 
`MvxBind: Error: 0,21 Empty binding target passed to MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry` 
and 
`MvxBind: Warning: 0,21 Failed to create target binding for binding  for -empty-`

I've tried a lot of options and tutorials but I couldn't get it working so far.

I'll appreciate any hint about what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

Change this:
`set.Bind(CustomView.Text).To(ViewModel.Text);`

To this:
`set.Bind(CustomView).For(c => c.Text).To(vm => vm.Text);`